# How does Elastic Search qualify a query as an expensive query?

Tags: elasticsearch

There is a feature in elastic search to turn on/off `allow_expensive_queries`.

What parameters does elastic search uses to filter out queries, I want to know how is query analysed.

I tried reading the source code but could not find relevant details.

Comment: There's an interesting ongoing discussion regarding this specific feature and it's usefulness: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/90898. The short answer is there is no clear definition of what "expensive" means, just "usual suspects"